# Expected a ; after declaration error c++ Xcode?

Tags: c++, xcode, class

So I was wondering if anyone can read over the code and see any errors:
This is the file with the errors

```
#ifndef Game_part_1_Cluenumber2_h
#define Game_part_1_Cluenumber2_h
#include <iostream>
#include "Clue.cpp"
#include "casesp1.h"
using namespace std;
int &refcrimetWo = crime;
int clue.setClues(10, 14, 14)(){    
}
void clueTwo()
{
    int
    clue.raNdom();
}
#endif
```

This is the class file:

```
#include "Clue.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include<fstream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
using namespace std;
class clue {
    string evidenceop1, evidenceop2, evidenceop3;
public:

    //    int choose (void);
    string werk = "";
    int setClues(int x,int y,int z);

    void raNdom(){


        srand(time(NULL));
        signed int x = rand() %3;
        switch(x){
            case 1:
                werk = evidenceop1;
                break;
            case 2:
                werk = evidenceop2;
                break;
            default:
                werk = evidenceop3;
                break;
        }




    }
//    void fInal(){return werk;};
} Clue;
```

Thank you so much, the error comes at the `int clue.setClues(10, 14, 14)(){}`

This is not the main file, but in the main file i never call the function

Comment: What do you think `int clue.setClues(10, 14, 14)(){}` does?

Comment: it is supposed to define the variables for the class clue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The compiler considers this statement as a declaration

```
int clue.setClues(10, 14, 14)(){
```

As for me I do not know what this statement means.

First of all you may not call functions in a namespace scope except their using in declarations as initializer expressions. And secondly functions are not called the way you wrote.

Comment: its supposed to define the values for the class clue

Comment: @Devilswin It is invalid construction. I said about this in my post.